# PHP File request/download script encoding as text/html

Tags: php, pdf, http-headers

I'm having an issue with this file download script. It takes in an ID, queries the filename, finds the extension, and sets the appropriate headers based on MIME type.

The issue is I THINK the header is being set to text/html instead of application/PDF in this case. It was working previously and now not so much. I've tried a simple force download script (http://webdesign.about.com/od/php/ht/force_download.htm) and that does work. Does anyone why this is happening?

Here is the code I'm using. (NOTE: This code was inherited. Just trying to fix this issue.)

```
<?php 
include("includes/function_lib.php");
//*******************************************************************************//
//*******************************************************************************//
// Download Code
    function output_file($file, $name, $mime_type='')
    {
        /*This function takes a path to a file to output ($file), 
        the filename that the browser will see ($name) and 
        the MIME type of the file ($mime_type, optional).
        If you want to do something on download abort/finish,
        register_shutdown_function('function_name');
        */
        if(!is_readable($file)) die('File not found or inaccessible!');

        $size = filesize($file);
        $name = rawurldecode($name);

        /* Figure out the MIME type (if not specified) */
        $known_mime_types=array(
        "pdf" => "application/pdf",
        "sql" => "text/plain",
        "txt" => "text/plain",
        "html" => "text/html",
        "htm" => "text/html",
        "exe" => "application/octet-stream",
        "zip" => "application/zip",
        "doc" => "application/msword",
        "xls" => "application/vnd.ms-excel",
        "ppt" => "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint",
        "gif" => "image/gif",
        "png" => "image/png",
        "jpeg"=> "image/jpg",
        "jpg" => "image/jpg",
        "php" => "text/plain"
        );

        if($mime_type=='')
        {
            $file_extension = strtolower(substr(strrchr($file,"."),1));
            if(array_key_exists($file_extension, $known_mime_types))
            {
                $mime_type=$known_mime_types[$file_extension];

            } 
            else 
            {
                $mime_type="application/force-download";
            }
        }

        @ob_end_clean(); //turn off output buffering to decrease cpu usage

        // required for IE, otherwise Content-Disposition may be ignored
        if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression'))
        ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');

        header('Content-Type: ' . $mime_type);
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$name.'"');
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

        /* The three lines below basically make the 
        download non-cacheable */
        header("Cache-control: private");
        header('Pragma: private');
        header("Expires: Mon, 5 Jun 2019 05:00:00 GMT");

        // multipart-download and download resuming support
        if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']))
        {
        list($a, $range) = explode("=",$_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'],2);
        list($range) = explode(",",$range,2);
        list($range, $range_end) = explode("-", $range);
        $range=intval($range);
        if(!$range_end) {
        $range_end=$size-1;
        } else {
        $range_end=intval($range_end);
        }

        $new_length = $range_end-$range+1;
        header("HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content");
        header("Content-Length: $new_length");
        header("Content-Range: bytes $range-$range_end/$size");
        } else {
        $new_length=$size;
        header("Content-Length: ".$size);
        }

        /* output the file itself */
        $chunksize = 3*(1024*1024); //you may want to change this
        $bytes_send = 0;
        if ($file = fopen($file, 'r'))
        {
        if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']))
        fseek($file, $range);

        while(!feof($file) && 
        (!connection_aborted()) && 
        ($bytes_send<$new_length)
        )
        {
        $buffer = fread($file, $chunksize);
        print($buffer); //echo($buffer); // is also possible
        flush();
        $bytes_send += strlen($buffer);
        }
        fclose($file);
        } else die('Error - can not open file.');

        die();
    }   

$data_action    = $_REQUEST['action'];

if($data_action == 'downloadfile') {
    if(isset($_REQUEST['file'])) {
        $file = $_REQUEST['file'];
    } else {
        $Id = $_REQUEST["id"];
        $sqlNewsletter = "select  case_file from tbl_case where case_id=$Id and deleteflag='active' and status='active'"; 
        $rsNewsletter  = mysql_query($sqlNewsletter);
        if(mysql_num_rows($rsNewsletter) > 0) {
            $rowNewsletter = mysql_fetch_object($rsNewsletter);
            $file = $rowNewsletter->case_file;
        }
    }
    $filename  = explode('/', $file);
    $name      = $filename[2];
    //$name = $file;
    $result = output_file($file, $file);
//}
?>

<?php
    //$result = $s->output_file($file, $name);
    //$s->pageLocation("index.php?pagename=database_backup&action=done&result=$result"); 
}
?>
```

Comment: Why are you using file extensions to determine mime types? There's `fileinfo()` to do that for you. file extensions can lie. fileinfo() looks at the actual file contents to figure out what they are. As well, you should NOT be turning off output buffering until AFTER you've output your header() calls. You risk disabling them by producing inadvertent output.

Comment: I can say for certain the file is a pdf and that MIME type is application/PDF. Again, I did not put this code together but I do need to fix it. I will try to swap out the file extension/MIME bit for fileinfo() instead. Is there any other thing that would cause text/html to be encoded instead of application/pdf?

Comment: Sure. If the header() calls fail because you already had output, then php will default to text/html. e.g. check you logs for "unable to send header - output already sent at line XXX" type messages.

Comment: I only found the following:

[Tue Jan 21 14:44:18 2014] [warn] [client xx.xxx.xx.xx] (104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server
[Tue Jan 21 14:44:18 2014] [error] [client xx.xxx.xx.xx] Premature end of script headers: articles.php